# Rebuilding a jpg from blob

Tags: php

Edited and started over to better describe my issue.

I have this code that displays an image from a database using blob data.

```
function getContent($db) {
    $query = "SELECT name, animalid, image, thumb FROM images ";
    $sql = $db->prepare($query);
    $sql->execute();
    return $sql->fetchAll();
}

$data = getContent($db);

    foreach($data as $row) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $image = $row['image'];
    $thumb = $row['thumb'];

    echo '<img src="data:thumb/jpg;charset=utf8;base64,'.$image.'">';   
}
```

This code displays a image on the page, when viewing the source code i see the blob data that the image is made from, what i need is to actually make an image that i can name properly.

How do i make a ******.jpg from the blob data?

Comment: Could you please refine your questions and code, which is obviously not a working snipped.

Answer (score 0):

Use `base64_encode`. You should use `image/jpeg` MIME type without `charset`.

```
function getContent($db) {
    $query = "SELECT name, animalid, image, thumb FROM images ";
    $sql = $db->prepare($query);
    $sql->execute();
    return $sql->fetchAll();
}

$data = getContent($db);

    foreach($data as $row) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $image = $row['image'];
    $thumb = $row['thumb'];

    // $image is the BLOB

    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($image).'">';   
}
```

Comment: That just gives me a broken image logo, when i got to source it still shows the blob data as well

Comment: @RichardHarper it should work if `image` column contains the BLOB.

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work i copied it straight in, oh yes sorry the $thumb also has blob data, same image different size.

Comment: I found this code in a diffrent post but have no idea how to actually get a ****.jpg to from it. string base64string = $image;
 byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64string);
 File.WriteAllBytes("test.jpg", data);

Comment: @RichardHarper Is your image JPEG?

Comment: i see where you are going so i tried echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($image).'">';    but still no luck?

Comment: @RichardHarper Correct MIME type is `image/jpeg`, not `image/jpg`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188556/discussion-between-jiwopene-and-richard-harper).